# looking to compare two directories using boolean statement

Tags: shell-script, diff

just looking to compare two directories and make sure that all files reside in both, I'm aware of the diff cmd but is there a way to use Boolean logic? if directory a contents ==  directory b contents print "true" else print "false" but don't know the syntax still new at scripting.

Comment: You have used both the [tag:macos] and the [tag:linux] tags. What Unix are you actually using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `diff` command and get the boolean result by exit code:

```
diff dir1/ dir2/ >/dev/null 2>&1
EXITCODE=$?
```

if `EXITCODE` variable is 0 the directories are identical, if 1 they are not identical, if 2 there is some problem, for example you do not have permission to read directory, file, etc.

For reference you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6971295/2908599). Also [take a look](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) on some `bash` exit code.

P.S. And from comment you can use code like this:

```
if diff dir1/ dir2/ >/dev/null 2>&1
 then echo true
 else echo false
fi
```

Comment: Or use the exit status directly: `if diff ... >/dev/null 2>&1; then echo same; else echo different; fi`.

Comment: @AlekNaomieBurtPilon please collect _all_ of the requirements and put them into your question. Using shasum256 is a completely different approach. Think about what you need, and then explain it so we can find an answer that will work for you.

Comment: okay sorry, want to compare two directories based on the hash values of the files within the folders the following script worked diff a c > /dev/null && echo Same || echo Different but wondering if you can add a way to check hash values of the files between the two directories then determine if they are the same or not.

Comment: @AlekNaomieBurtPilon, this is totally different approach and question. Feels free to create new question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: @AlekNaomieBurtPilon If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting an answer marks the issue as resolved.